# Which cultures are big-endian?

Tags: list-of-languages, numerals

I do not really know where to post such a question, so please bear with me if you think there were a better stackexchange for it.

[Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) refers to how we order elements from multiple scales. As such, ordering from coarser to finer scales is called *big-endian* ; the opposite is called *little-endian*.

The Wikipedia article discusses merely about its implications in computer architecture, but its scope is actually much broader and we can find it in everyday life.

Indeed, I identified at least four instances where endianness matters :

- personal identity : should we put first name before or after last name ? Well, obviously English language itself answers the question (in a little-endian way), but many Asian countries beg to differ ;
- dates : should we write day/month/year (little-endian) or year-month-day (big-endian) ?
- addresses : should we write *Number Street City Country* (little-endian) or *Country City Street Number* (big-endian) ?
- numbers obviously : we usually agree to write that half a kilometre is *0.5 km* (big-endian), but we could have convened to write *5.0 km* (little-endian) ; for instance, Arabic speakers do write *0.5 km*, but read it from right to left, hence in a little-endian way.

From a psychological point of view, endianness is about choosing between prioritising global or local. Let me explain.

If you're asking someone today's date, you probably actually are just asking what *day* it is. You are likely very well aware of current year and even month, and as such not interested in them. One might reply "It is the fourth" without any further detail and you would be perfectly fine with this answer. You are interested in the finer scale as it helps you precise *locally*. This is little-endian logic.

As an opposed example, if you are a bit interested in Roman history, you will probably learn that its Western part fell in 476, but you probably won't even try to memorise the specific month, not to say the specific day. This is big-endian logic, where coarser scale helps you precise *globally*.
Likewise, if you want to chronologically sort old administrative papers (say, paid bills) which span over more than a decade, you will first look for years, then months, and finally days. Maybe you won't even be interested in the day if it isn't necessary for you to sort. Which is why international norm for date time notation (ISO 8601) is big-endian.

Except for numbers, Western countries are mostly little-endian. Few exceptions include United States and Germany, which are sometimes quite weird using what we could call *middle-endian* (basically meaning there is no logic at all), respectively for dates and addresses.

Also, German would read « 132 » as « ein hundert zwei und dreißig » (litteraly « one hundred two and thirty ») which is *middle-endian* again, as opposed to English which is big-endian here (reading hundreds, then tens, then units).

However, Chinese people seem to be big-endian for all of these four aforementioned subjects. Which other countries or cultures also are fully big-endian ?

Is there any culture which is fully little-endian ?

Comment: I think you're looking for stuff like Nisbett's work on cultural differences in perception, a line of work reviewed here: psyarxiv.com/c57ep/download?format=pdf I am definitely among the skeptics for this. For a start, the only correct taxonomy of cultures is obviously New Zealand vs Everyone Else, so I'm not on-board for some important chunks of the initial premise. But there are people out there making a serious effort to answer your question, best of luck to all of you.

Comment: Thanks steve ! I guess I am skeptical too about making broad dichotomies between cultures, but I'll have an interested eye on the paper you mentioned. Let's say I was first interested in a cartography, rather than an a posteriori analysis (which is a biassed reasoning).

I didn't quite get the joke about New Zealand by the way, how would they be so much different to every other people ? :)

Comment: Two factual errors: Arabic writes numerals from left to right (opposite the direction of the letters). German says "einhundertzweiunddreißig" (not "und zwei").

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(linguistics).

Comment: While I can see how bare numbers could be categorised this way perhaps, I can't see it for dates - "1st of January" and "January 1st" are equally valid and natural for me.

Comment: @fdb : thanks for your remark. I corrected my German mistake. As for Arabic, how do they write 123456789 in the middle of a sentence ? Do you mean they estimate how much space the number is going to take, leave an appropriate blank and start writing 1, 2, 3, …, 9 from left to right ? Then move hand back to first digit and pursue writing right to left ? This seems impractical but that would make it interesting.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what they do. If they are using a computer the program will automatically switch the direction of writing for the numeral. Please note that I am talking about writing, not speech. In modern Arabic you say "thousand and nine hundred and nine and ninety", though in classical Arabic they said "nine and ninety and nine hundred after one thousand".

Comment: @fdb : very interesting. Is it possible that this left-to-right numeral writing is modern too, or has it always been the case ? If I understood it right, old reading was pure little-endian but now it seems merely big-endian with a twist for small numbers (less than a hundred). I suppose this twist is due to small numbers being used more often, hence conventions are harder to change ?

Comment: The Arabic numerals (as we call them) were introduced from India (where they were always written with biggest digits on the left) in the 9th century. The older Arabic system of using the letters of the alphabet as numbers writes the highest digits on the right.

Comment: So they used to write numbers in a big-endian way (from right-to-left), but were reading them in a little-endian way ? Meaning they were, in those times, basically reading them left-to-right ?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: Chinese is quite consistently big-endian, but even there you do say and write “zero point five”, not “five point zero” if you’re referring to half of one. I wonder what type of endianness best fits counting systems like Irish (112 boats = céad is dhá bhád déag = hundred and two boats -teen [embedded object], but 157 boats = céad seachtó is cúig mbád = hundred fifty and seven boats [non-embedded]) or Danish (157 boats = hundrede syvoghalvtreds både = hundred seven and half-of-the-third score boat).

Comment: It sounds like this is related -- perhaps closely, perhaps distantly -- to the ordering phenomena addressed by Cooper and Ross in their famous ["World Order"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf) paper.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet small correction to your Gaeilge, you've written 175; 157 boats = céad caoga is seacht mbád

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Gah, you’re right! I initially wrote 175, but then later  changed it to 157 for some reason… not sure why? Ní foláir nó go raibh mé ar mearbhaillín giota beag ag an am…

Comment: Hungarian is another example of a fully big-endian culture/language

Comment: @maritsm Hungarian is mostly big-endian, but it does have elements of little- or mid-endianness as well, such as addresses (as far as I know usually mid-endian, going 1-3-2-4 = name, city, street, country).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness is about computing, not natural languages. I really do not think the examples provided can be said to be: coarser to finer or finer to coarser.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hungarian adresses are in the order or country-zipcode-city-street-number.

Comment: I’m just curious - why is it called big-endian when you have the little thing at the end and the big thing at the start, rather than the other way around?

Comment: @maritsm I don’t live in Hungary, but that’s not what Magyar Posta says, at least not in their [international addressing instructions](https://www.posta.hu/static/internet/download/correct_addressing.pdf): section 1.2.1 specifies that the order should be Recipient – City/town (+ district) – Street + number (+ additional) – Postcode.

Comment: @GrahamH. My understanding is that it's because of eggs. Specifically, the phrases "little-endian" and "big-endian" first appeared in _Gulliver's Travels_ in 1726, and described opposing factions of people who ate hard-boiled eggs starting at either the little end or the big end. The phrases were borrowed to refer to the two possible ways of sending a number: starting with the least significant bit ("little end") or the most significant bit ("big end").

Comment: And those are -- very loosely -- correlated to the two principal ways sending sentences: starting with the predicate or ending with the predicate. Roughly half of the world's languages follow those methods. Over half are SOV, with SVO and VSO accounting for most of the rest, and SVO works like VSO in most syntactic ways. I've never heard them called little- and big-endian, but it could fit. You'd hafta decide whether VPs are bigger than NPs, or something. Verbs have more fun, but that doesn't make them bigger.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I do live in Hungary, and I lived here my whole life. My very own address card that is issued by the government uses the order I just specified. I think what you found must be some Posta-internal standard, since I've never seen this ordering elsewhere. I'm not sure why Posta wants people to address letters in this order. I don't really have any mail I got recently to check how they are addressed, but I can assure you that common parlance uses the big-endian ordering, and pretty much all official communication does too.

Comment: @maritsm Interesting, thank you! Does actual usage extend the big-endianness to giving the recipient’s name last as well (as in Chinese and generally also Japanese)?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No. The name and the address are generally considered to be separate and usually the name is given first. Although the name itself is always in big-endian format (Family name first)

Comment: @fdb I have never heard of something like "nine and ninety and nine hundred after one 
thousand" in classical arabic. It would have, pretty much always, been "two thousand except one". It is weird, though it is also quite nice in a way. But it may be a matter of the specific texts I have read using this, so I may be wrong about it being common practice back then.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM. It is normal in mathematical and astronomical texts, and in historians.

Comment: @maritsm : thanks for your contribution !

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet : though I will consider hungarian culture to be fully big-endian, your remark is interesting, as indeed name should come _after_ in a big-endian logic. Never thought about this one ; fascinating that chinese and japanese cultures are still consistent with this case.

Comment: @jlawler : no, SVO versus SOV should rather be compared to infix and postfix notations, respectively.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation .

Answer (score 14):

This is potentially a very interesting question, but it suffers from conflation of “language”, “culture”, and “country”. It is the same sort of confusion that happens when people who do not speak gendered languages imagine that French people think their hands are female (la main) and their feet are male (le pied). I assure you that they do not.

To take just one of your examples: British English says day/month/year, while US English says month/day/year. Here 9/11 is the 9th of November, but there it is the 11th of September. Does this say anything at all about mentality or culture? I think not. Like most things in language this is merely a matter of convention.

Comment: Being a native French speaker I have no doubt about your assertion :)
I also agree with the lack of rigour you mention between language/culture/country… I do not really know which concept would be most appropriate. Maybe none of them.

I really do not want to extrapolate too much about it. I'm merely interested in hypothetical rules. For instance, is there a correlation between dates and addresses conventions ? Are there some conventions that never occur ? Maybe then, move on to ask what are the areas of common conventions, and why these areas share it (common history, cultural influences)?

Answer (score 0):

One example of endianness in language is the traditional [Welsh vigesimal counting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_numerals), and its Celtic counterparts in Cornish, Breton and Gaelic.

To give examples, the number 34 would be expressed as *pedwar ar ddeg ar hugain* (four on ten on twenty), and the number 97 would be *saith ar ddeg ar bedair ugain* (seven on ten on four twenties).

This is not common to all vigesimal systems, as French would describe the latter number as *quatre-vingt-dix-sept* (four twenties, ten, seven).

This does not extend into all aspects of the language. Names were traditionally described as 'X son/daughter of Y' (e.g. *Dafydd ap Gwilym*), similar to the *O'* and *Mac* prefixes of Irish and Scottish families and clans.

Comment: The Welsh numbers are _little_-endian, not big-endian.

Comment: Also don't forget Gaelic vigesimal

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Duly corrected.

Comment: @OmarL I can't speak (for) Gaelic, but please feel free to add your experience to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Endianness is not a natural concept at all. Nature itself cannot care less about endianness, in the same way that it cannot care less about square roots. They are human-made abstract concepts, to help them (the humans) to explain the nature around them.

Endianness is especially related to computers because there everything has to be properly sorted, explained, findable etc. It is 100% scientific.

On the other hand, there are few things less scientific than languages. That is why it is many time almost impossible to translate one text from a language into another text in another language - because the structure of the languages is as original and varied as the people who created those languages.

I will give you some examples that clearly show that analyzing languages with endianness is not going to end well:

1. The US notation for dates is MM / DD / YY - that is middle / small / big - is that little endian or big endian?
2. Numerals in German - they write 123 and read "one hundred 3 and twenty". Which endianness is it when they read? As far as I understand, there was a habit in English to treat numbers like this also (at least according to the "old" English books that I read). So while there is some endianness in writing, there is no endianness in reading.
3. The French language. They write 99 and read "four times twenty and ten and nine". Please try to guess the endianness of that text.
4. Roman numerals! 11 = XI = 10+1, while 9 = IX = -1+10. Mixed endianness again.

Bottom line: languages are not good or bad. They just are - like trees and like stars. The issue here is that endianness is not the proper tool for the analysis of languages.

Consider the following (jocular) questions:

- how many meters of water are in a bottle?
- how many liters of water does the Amazon river have at coordinates (X,Y).

That is the result of using good tools for unsuitable jobs.

Comment: It’s true of course that endianness is not a natural concept – but then neither is human language to begin with. There are tendencies for some languages to be either big- or little-endian in how they view the world. Chinese and Japanese are the most unambiguous I can think of, being extremely big-endian in every way. The opposite seems rarer – Welsh is potentially an example (but only when using the traditional counting system). Most fall somewhere in between. I don’t think that invalidates endianness as a linguistic notion – it just means that it’s only relevant to _some_ languages.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I agree, you are mostly right. I only wanted to underline that endianness can only partially be applied to some parts of some languages. For the rest, For other aspects, endianness is so mixed it is not worth bringing it into discussion much. Some things just have to be accepted. In many paces, the address on an envelope is written as street, number, city, Country - with the zip code there somewhere in between. So again, mixed endianness.

Comment: [better: couldn't care less, :)]